# Incorporate default media player into HTML (Samsung Tizen Browser)

Tags: html, tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I'm developing a website and I want to incorporate the default media player into my HTML to reproduce a video on TizenBrowser.
Instead of using the  tag I want to incorporate the default media player.
Can anyone help me or confirm that what I want to do is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Besides [Using Video Element](http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/guides/multimedia/media-playback/using-video-elements#) ,

May be you are looking for [AVPlay API](http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/guides/multimedia/media-playback/using-avplay#).

Comment: The idea is to use the native video player from samsung tizen into the website. For what I understand the AVPlay API is for aplications only.
Is there any way I could get the video player and embed it on my website?

Comment: No, You can't. By Developing a Tizen Web app you had a chance , But from a WebSite-> No.